# Few Problems after installing Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: boot, drivers, screen

i tried ubuntu last year, all was working fine, there was no lag,
and now again i was trying and downloaded official latest lte ubuntu 12.04
there are few problems im facing are,
 1. Lagy animations: last year when i installed there wasn’t lag but today i installed again latest version is having lag while animations like minimise,etc..
   i even installed latest drivers, my pc config is Intel i5 2310, 8 gb ram ddr3, Ati 6870 1gb ddr5, drivers are installed..

1. Ubuntu Logo bug(simple text): i installed ubuntu on W7 using Wubi, after install successful, first boot there was logo before login screen, like small UBUNTU with shining etc, i liked it, so, then i updated my Ubuntu it takes hour and after restart i lost that Nice Logo, now there is only a txt written like Ubuntu 12.04 not a pic, these things i dont like about ubuntu...
2. GPU info not correct: i installed my GPU drivers, but when i see Info from settings>Details>Graphics i see there is " VESA: BARTS " written on Drivers and Standard.. there must written Ati 6870 blabla.

These are the problems i am facing, Please help me and give me chance to enjoy Ubuntu xD
Thanks in Advance...

Comment: The text on boot is usually a result of having to use proprietary drivers. While it is ugly if you are a new user I recommend just leaving it as is.

Comment: Thanx for help, but the thread which you shown me, is that will work on ATI hardware too? edit. m using 64 bit

Comment: Maybe, maybe not, I recommend just leaving it as messing with it if you don't know what you are doing might render your system unbootable!

Comment: ok but,i was really wondering about that logo, anyways thanks for help :(